# solace pub sub + REST consumer Authentication schema client-certificate

Tags: solace

we recently upgraded our solace VMR to pub sub+, I am trying to configure rest delivery point using SSL. I created a rest consumer and set authentication schema as client-certificate, it is not taking and displaying as none. I did all this from CLI.The ssl settings looks good default cipher and trusted CN. the rest consumer was down with failure reason " Remote SSL handshake failed: sslv3 alert handshake failure"

I suspect solace is not sending certificate when it is trying to connect. Any thoughts on setting Authentication scheme as client-certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the rest-consumer is configured correctly to use SSL, and to authenticate with client-certificate. The CLI commands are:

```
show message-vpn <vpn_name> rest rest-consumer <rest-consumer_name> authentication 
show message-vpn <vpn_name> rest rest-consumer <rest-consumer_name> detail
```

Also, check that the CA of the remote host certificate is trusted with CLI command:

```
show certificate-authority ca-name * cert
```

At the minimum, the root issuer of the remote host certificate must be one of the configured certificate-authorities in that CLI command.

If those check out, ensure that the remote endpoint is indeed requesting client-certificates in the first place. You can check the raw packets on the wire with Wireshark:

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: <remote-host-ip>, Dst: <solace-ip>
...
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
    ...
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
    ...
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
    ...
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        ...
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate Request
            Handshake Type: Certificate Request (13)
```

Then, you should see a client certificate response from the Solace container:

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: <solace-ip>, Dst: <remote-host-ip>
...
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        ...
        Handshake Protocol: Certificate
            Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
            ...
            Certificates (xxx bytes)
                ...
                Certificate (...,id-at-commonName=...)
```